# how to draw a circle around the marker on google fusion tables?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geometry, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I'm using google fusion tables I want to draw a circle around my markers. how do I do that? if there is something I should write in the javascript what is it? am not a web developer so I dunno :S

Answer (score 0):

See the Circle overlay [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) The real issue will be getting the location of your markers.

Comment: For tables up to 250 rows, Google Chart Tools can be used to get the data out of Fusion Tables http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: You can also use the "undocumented" Fusion Table JSONP API as shown in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9778985/1211981)