# Marker count in fusion table map

Tags: google-maps, count, google-fusion-tables, legend

I went through these two links: [first](http://michelleminkoff.com/2012/02/05/how-to-count-queried-rows-in-a-google-fusion-table/) and [second](https://github.com/derekeder/FusionTable-Map-Template/wiki/List-search-results) which explains how to add count of marker in fusion table map layer. I tried the same technique in my sample map but it didn't work. Actually i need the count of critical, optimal, normal transforers seperately and the total of all. Also i want to know that can I add these counts in map legend?

Comment: EDIT: My sample [map link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a year ago, I posted an answer with example code which is the same approach taken in your "first" link.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778985. See the getFTCount() function.
The problem with both these examples is that they are old and use the deprecated FT SQL API, not the V1.0 API.

You will need a Google API key.  And jQuery.  The one thing you'll need to change in the code is:

```
var apiKey = "XXXXXX";
var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
var queryUrlTail = '&key=' + apiKey + '&callback=?';
```

**Update:** I fixed your jsfiddle to make it work. Couple of issues:

- The new api returns data.columns and data.rows, not data.table.rows.
- I guess the new API is returning json integers, not strings and jquery seems to object to passing numbers to $("#div_id").html() or .append().

Note: the empty string before the count number

`$('#count').html(('' + data.rows[0]));`

http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/8/

Comment: Is there any such samples?

Comment: There is sample code in the answer linked above.  Look at the second example: getFTCount() but change the query Head and Tail var's.

Comment: Yes. The example just does an alert(count) when the count is returned but you could do whatever you want with it. Store it in a global then redraw your legend.

Comment: I updated my sample [map here](http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/3/). It didn't working with FT API v1